# Accuracy is 84 percent but prediction results are wrong

Tags: python, lstm

Here is my complete code. I'm trying to predict protein classes from protein sequences.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

# Transform labels to one-hot
lb = LabelBinarizer()
Y = lb.fit_transform(df.classification)


from keras.preprocessing import text, sequence
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#maximum length of sequence, everything afterwards is discarded!
max_length = 500

#create and fit tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(char_level=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(seqs)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(seqs)
X = sequence.pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_length)



from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional, Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

embedding_vecor_length = 128
max_length = 500
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index)+1, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=512)
```

This is accuracy of the model
train-acc = 0.8485087800799034
test-acc = 0.8203392530062913

and my prediction results are:

```
[9.65313017e-02 1.33084046e-04 1.73516816e-03 4.62103529e-08
  8.45071673e-03 2.42734270e-04 3.54182965e-04 2.88571493e-04
  1.99087553e-05 8.92244339e-01]
 [8.89207274e-02 1.99566261e-04 1.76228161e-04 2.08527595e-02
  1.64435953e-01 2.83987029e-03 1.53038520e-02 7.07270563e-01
  5.16798650e-07 2.19354401e-08]
 [9.36142087e-01 6.09822795e-02 3.55492946e-09 2.19342492e-05
  5.41335670e-04 1.89031591e-04 2.66434945e-04 1.84136129e-03
  1.54582867e-05 3.31551647e-10]
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. I'm stuck with it and don't know how to solve it. Also, I'm kindda new to deep learning.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: the prediction results. I mean isn't there supposed to be a '1' value in prediction array? which will indicate the prediction class. 1 for the true class and 0 for all the other classes. I'm stuck with this.

Comment: and thanks for the response.

Comment: are these results are acceptable? with these prediction results?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain what's going on in my answer

Comment: Thanks. 
I'll be waiting.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your last layer has an activation function of softmax function

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

So when you predict values it passes through that softmax function in the last layer which gives you those strange-looking float values.

Now, basically what the softmax function is doing here is that it normalizes the input values given to the function and normalizes them in range (0, 1) and all the components will add up to 1. You can read more about the softmax function here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function.

On how can you find the prediction label id you just need to find the maximum value's index in the array and you will have your label id they are pointing to.
You can use numpy argmax function to find maximum values index in multidimensional arrays. You can refer here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Comment: i mistakenly flagged one comment on this answer

Comment: so basically I have to pass the prediction results to the argmax function?

Comment: is it not necessary for the true class to be 1 in case of this probability softmax function?

Comment: Yes, and no its not necessary it all depends on the function input values. Ideally true class value should be close to 1